# 404 on Prestashop 1.5 under nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, prestashop

I have a problem with nginx giving a 404 error on a Prestashop 1.5.4.1 site.

This is the URL returning the 404:
www.domain.com/es/index.php?controller=order-confirmation

The prestashop is under multilanguage enviroment. Then I have:

- www.domain.com/en/
- www.domain.com/es/
- www.domain.com/fr/
- www.domain.com/de/

The URL rewriting runs fine, except when the url have the "index.php". Then nginx returns de 404.

I think the problem is on nginx virtualhost configuration, but I don't know what it's failing.

My nginx configuration: http://pastebin.com/CFQ5hwNX

That nginx configuration runs perfect on a Prestashop with only 1 domain (without the /lang/ on the url).